# Тире при сочинении с союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, ссп

*Тишина была такой полной и угрюмой, а небо таким душным, что мальчику казалось — раздайся хоть один только резкий звук, и в природе произойдёт что-то страшное (Кат.).*

Почему здесь перед союзом "и" стоит запятая, а не тире, ведь есть взаимообусловленность событий? Чтобы избежать двух тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, так, чтобы избежать двух тире, ведь здесь знак факультативен: в сложносочинённом предложении больше прав имеет запятая,тире ставится при неожиданном присоединении, а неожиданное оно или обычное предложение - решает автор.

И после *казалось* по правилам не тире, а двоеточие, но в современной пунктуации возможна такая замена, оба знака говорят о причинно-следственных связях,  предупреждают о паузе, а какая она, о чём говорит - вроде бы теперь нет разницы, хотя раньше считалось за ошибку.

Comment: Нет, первое тире здесь на месте: "Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта" (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151).